# why does pidof not work for update-manager

Tags: 22.04, kill

I am considering running a busy loop to kill the `update-manager` popup as it is way too annoying. but I get no result from

```
echo $(pidof update-manager)
```

but firefox returns its numerous PID's

```
echo $(pidof firefox)
```

I've tried running it with `sudo`
I want to get to

```
kill $(pidof update-manager)
```

I alternatively extract the column to `ps | grep update-manager` but `pidof` should work, as there would only be one instance of it at any time .

Comment: XY problem. Maybe there are better solutions to solve your real problem.

Comment: yes, as I suggested, but still it should work for any process surely. though the best option would be a Ubuntu option for daily reminders (not every boot), or no reminders, I will manage my own affairs.